# Wordpress, Bootstrap, id elements in foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I'm using Wordpress locally so I don't have actual working code to show.

I'm using a foreach loop to load blocks of content.

I don't know how many blocks there are but they need to be 4 on a row.

This jsfiddle shows the layout hard coded - https://jsfiddle.net/buen7kps/1/

My probelm is I need to have the last line of blocks symmetrical like in the jsfiddle exmaple.

It's symmetrical in the example using 'offset' on the first block in the last row.

So my problem is how can I identify if it's the last row and if it's the 3rd, 2nd or last block.

This is the foreach code that places 4 blocks in a row.

```
        $information_blocks = $block['information_blocks'];

            echo '<div class="row">';

            $block_count = 0;

            foreach( $information_blocks as $information_block){

                if($block_count == 4){
                    $block_count = 0;
        ?>          
                </div><div class="row">


                    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <div class="article-info-block">
                            <h4><?php echo $information_block['information_block_title']; ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $information_block['information_block_text']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php

                }else{
                ?>              
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <div class="article-info-block">
                            <h4><?php echo $information_block['information_block_title']; ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $information_block['information_block_text']; ?></p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                <?php
                    $block_count ++;
                    }
                }   

                ?>  


            </div>  

        <?php
        }   
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is a little redundant. You can consolidate it and test for a final row by keeping track of total blocks and number of blocks incremented. Not sure if this is exactly how you're looking to center your final row (they won't center perfectly on odd number of blocks in row), but give this a try:

```
$information_blocks = $block['information_blocks'];
$total = count($information_blocks);
$total_iterated = 0;
$block_count = 0;
$offset_set = FALSE;

foreach($information_blocks as $information_block){
    $offset = '';
    if($block_count == 0){
        echo '<div class="row">';
        $left = $total - $total_iterated;
        if($left < 4 && !$offset_set){
            if($left == 3) $offset = 'col-sm-offset-2';
            elseif($left == 2) $offset = 'col-sm-offset-3';
            elseif ($left == 1) $offset = 'col-sm-offset-5';
            $offset_set = TRUE;
        }
    }
?>

     <div class="col-sm-3 <?php echo $offset ?>">
        <div class="article-info-block">
            <h4><?php echo $information_block['information_block_title']; ?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $information_block['information_block_text']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
    $block_count++;
    if($block_count == 4 || $total - $total_iterated == 1){
        echo '</div>';
        $block_count = 0;
    }
    $total_iterated++;

}
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, your code works on the first row, but on the second row it is adding the offset class to all blocks so they are all offsetting. instead of just the first one in that row

Answer (score 1):

Hi @ttmt try this in now it's in CORE PHP if any problem with WordPress info me i will help you.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    .col-sm-3{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <?php

  $information_blocks = array('Test 1','Test 2','Test 3','Test 4','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5','Test 5');


  echo '<div class="row">';

  $block_count = 0;

  $count_block = count($information_blocks);

  $mod_val = $count_block % 4;
  $count_block - $mod_val;
  echo "<div class='row'>";
  $block_count = 0;
  foreach( $information_blocks as $information_block){


      $fooset_calss = "";
    if($block_count == ($count_block - $mod_val)){
        if($mod_val == 1){
            $block_class = 9;
        }
        elseif($mod_val == 2){
            $block_class = 6;
        }
        elseif($mod_val == 3){
            $block_class = 3;
        }

        $fooset_calss = "col-sm-offset-".$block_class;
    }
      ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3 <?php echo $fooset_calss; ?>">
        <div class="article-info-block">
            <h4><?php echo $information_block ?></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php   
    $block_count ++;
    }   
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```